# Numpy vectorize function with non-scalar output

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to vectorize a function that outputs a list. I wish to feed it all values from a numpy list and have it return a matrix, such that each row is an output for an element in the input vector.

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, n):
    o = []
    for i in range(n):
        o.append(x+i)
    return o

vec_func = np.vectorize(func)
matrix = vec_func(np.asarray([0, 1, 2]), 10)
```

however i get the error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

how can i fix this?

Comment: You want to return `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]`?

Comment: @roganjosh yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`frompyfunc` might be better:

```
In [525]: def fun(x):
     ...:     return x+.1, x+.2, x+.3
     ...:
```

I specify 1 input, 3 output values.  It returns dtype object:

```
In [526]: np.frompyfunc(fun,1,3)(np.arange(5))
Out[526]: 
(array([0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1], dtype=object),
 array([0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2], dtype=object),
 array([0.3, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 4.3], dtype=object))
```

That's a tuple of 3 arrays.  They can be turned into one 2d array with `stack`:

```
In [527]: np.stack(_, 1)
Out[527]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
       [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
       [2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
       [3.1, 3.2, 3.3],
       [4.1, 4.2, 4.3]], dtype=object)
```

I could take it a further step with a `astype(float)`.

I assume, of course, that this is a toy func.  For something this simple there's no need to use `vectorize`.

```
In [528]: fun(np.arange(5))
Out[528]: 
(array([ 0.1,  1.1,  2.1,  3.1,  4.1]),
 array([ 0.2,  1.2,  2.2,  3.2,  4.2]),
 array([ 0.3,  1.3,  2.3,  3.3,  4.3]))
```

All that `vectorize` needs is the `otypes` parameter:

```
In [536]: np.vectorize(fun, otypes='ddd')(np.arange(5))
Out[536]: 
(array([ 0.1,  1.1,  2.1,  3.1,  4.1]),
 array([ 0.2,  1.2,  2.2,  3.2,  4.2]),
 array([ 0.3,  1.3,  2.3,  3.3,  4.3]))
```

If the function returns an array instead of a tuple or list, we could use `signature`:

```
In [546]: def fun(x):
     ...:     return np.array([x+.1, x+.2, x+.3])

In [547]: np.vectorize(fun, signature='()->(n)')(np.arange(5))
Out[547]: 
array([[ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3],
       [ 1.1,  1.2,  1.3],
       [ 2.1,  2.2,  2.3],
       [ 3.1,  3.2,  3.3],
       [ 4.1,  4.2,  4.3]])
```

Or with the original tuple/list case, wrap it in a lambda, `np.vectorize(lambda x:np.array(fun(x)), signature='()->(n)')`

Experience suggests that the `frompyfunc` approach is fastest.  `vectorize` with otypes is a bit slower (but it uses `frompyfunc`).  `signature` is newer method, using different code, and somewhat slower.

---

With your new `func`, the `signature` approach still works.  I added `excluded` so it doesn't try to `broadcast` the `n` argument:

```
In [553]: np.vectorize(lambda x,n:np.array(func(x,n)), signature='()->(n)',excluded=[1])(np.arange(5),3)
Out[553]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [554]: np.vectorize(lambda x,n:np.array(func(x,n)), signature='()->(n)',excluded=[1])(np.arange(5),7)
Out[554]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: thanks! using multiple return values is not an option (afaik) as my toy function was a bit too oversimplified. in fact, the size of the output list is dynamic. Passing a numpy array directly is also not possible. I tried the otype parameter, but passed the wrong type. But If I understand correctly, this solution also fails because of the  dynamic return size. I updated my original toy function to capture a bit more of the complexity.